# Drawing a frame or box around parts of a syntactic tree using tikz-qtree

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to make boxes around parts of my tree, but I find no command to do so. I have tried the `qtree` package, which has the `!qframesubtree` that can do the job, but only for complete subtrees. What I want to do is to draw one box around the upper part of the tree (including the IP) and another box around the rest of the tree (including the VP).

```
\begin{exe} 
\ex \Tree [.IP Spec [.I\1 I [.VP Spec [.V\1 V XP ] ] ] ] 
\end{exe}
```

Any tips on how to do this.

I include a simple drawing of the desired result. [image]

EDIT: With the comments below I have now solved the problem. This is the code I ended up with:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom{}}},
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} sn edges,
[IP, tikz={\node [draw, fit=()(Spec)(Ibar)(I)]{};}, s sep=3em,
    [{Spec}, name=Spec]
    [I',name=Ibar, l sep=2em, s sep=6.5em,
        [I, name=I ]        
    [VP, tikz={\node [draw, inner sep=0.03em, fit=()(!1)(!ll)]{};}
        [Spec]
        [V', 
            [V]
            [XP]] ]] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can accept [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) instead of `qtree`, it's easy to do something similar to what you want.

`tikz={\node [draw, red, fit=()(!1)(!ll)]{};}` is an option which calls `TiKZ` to draw a node which fits the present node, its first child and last grandchild.

The green square could be also written with `tikz={\node [draw, green, fit to tree]{};}`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=5mm, fit=band}
[IP, tikz={\node [draw, red, fit=()(!1)(!ll)]{};}, 
 [Spec] 
   [I` [I]
       [VP, tikz={\node [draw, green, fit=()(!1)(!ll)]{};}
           [Spec]
           [V' [V]
              [XP]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Whilst I myself would recommend using the `forest` solution above, here's a way to do it in `tikz-qtree` by using the `fit` library that comes together with `tikz` to fit `tikz`'s nodes into a box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.\node(ip){IP}; \node(specip){Spec}; [.\node(ibar){I$'$}; \node(i){I}; [.\node(vp){VP}; \node(specvp){Spec}; [.V$'$ V \node(xp){XP}; ] ] ] ]
\node[draw,fit=(vp)(specvp)(xp)]{};
\node[draw,fit=(ip)(specip)(ibar)(i)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** I've edited the code to address your question in the comment to this answer. Note that it is also possible to use `tikzset` to tweak the distance between the tree's nodes so as to stop the boxes touching the nodes they aren't meant to be touching.

Comment: Many thanks! A furhter question. Is there any way to make the VP escape the upper box?

Comment: @DavidKroik Indeed it is. See the edited answer.

Comment: @PavelRudnev, I am using your solution - works nicely so far. One question though: Is there an easy way to attach the tree edges to the top of the boxes? Currently, the edges reach inside the boxes. Thanks!