# Make TikZ nodes connect to TikZ tree edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree, tikz-node

This is a question from a comment in this question:

[Drawing a frame or box around parts of a syntactic tree using tikz-qtree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233754/drawing-a-frame-or-box-around-parts-of-a-syntactic-tree-using-tikz-qtree)

I'm not getting any answer to my comment, which is why I'm asking a new question now; not sure if this is the right thing to do.

I'm trying to make the edges of the TikZ tree below connect to the nodes (or: boxes) surrounding the leaves. E.g., the edge from `Top Node` should connect from the bottom of the node `tn` towards the top of both nodes `lhl1s` and `rhl1s`, etc., all the way through the tree. Currently, the edges reach inside the leaves.

My hunch is that I should not be using a tree at all for this - or is there a simple way to do it with `\Tree`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north},level 2+/.style={level distance=1.25cm,sibling distance=30mm}]
    \Tree [.\node(tn){Top Node};
              [.\node(lhl1s){Left-Hand Level 1 Sister};
              ]
              [.\node(rhl1s){Right-Hand Level 1 Sister};
                  [.\node(rhl2s1){Right-Hand Level 2 Sister};
                  ]
                  [.\node(rhl2s2){Right-Hand Level 2 Sister};
                 ]
                 ]
          ]
    \node[draw,fit=(tn)]{};
    \node[draw,fit=(lhl1s)]{};
    \node[draw,fit=(rhl1s)]{};
    \node[draw,fit=(rhl2s1)]{};
    \node[draw,fit=(rhl2s2)]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A TikZ Tree}
\label{tikz-tree}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with using a tree I suppose, but instead of adding all the extra nodes to draw the boxes, just draw the border of the default nodes in the tree, by adding `draw` to the `every tree node` style.

(I changed from the `center` environment to `\centering`, cf. [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables))

As cfr mentions in a comment, because the text in the various nodes (may) have different height and depth, this makes the height of the boxes vary. You could fix that by adding something like `text height=2ex,text depth=0.5ex` to the `every tree node` style (for `tikz-qtree`), or in the `for tree={..}` (for `forest`, below). However, you can also be a bit sneaky, and use `font=\strut` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every tree node/.style={
    draw, %%% added
%    inner sep=5pt, % if you want more space inside the nodes
    align=center,
    anchor=north,
    font=\strut},
  level 2+/.style={
    level distance=1.25cm,
    sibling distance=10mm}]
    \Tree [.{Top Node}
              [.{Left-Hand Level 1 Sister}
              ]
              [.{Right-Hand Level 1 Sister}
                  [.{Right-Hand Level 2 Sister}
                  ]
                  [.{Right-Hand Level 2 Sister}
                 ]
                 ]
          ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A TikZ Tree}
\label{tikz-tree}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `forest` you get a more compact tree by default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,font=\strut}
[Top Node
  [Left-Hand Level 1 Sister]
  [Right-Hand Level 1 Sister
  [Right-Hand Level 2 Sister
  ]
  [Right-Hand Level 2 Sister]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{A forest Tree}
\label{tikz-tree}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice, thanks for this! I actually like the more "spread-out" look of `Tree` rather than the more compact look of the `forest` package.

Comment: @SebastianSulger You can add `fit=rectangle` or `fit=band` to easily get a less compact tree in Forest, which is more flexible generally.

Comment: (+1) Maybe setting a standard `text height` would be good here?

Comment: @cfr Good point, I didn't really notice that.